# Editing wfs layer

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I've tried replicating tutorial on how to edit WFS with OpenLayers(https://medium.com/@goldrydigital/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-16-6fb6a820ac58) but with my own WFS layer from Geoserver. Need some Javascript help finding what's wrong with it.

I managed to load the WFS and my basemap successfully and managed to get the buttons to show up. The buttons appear correctly like in the working example , for some reason the geometry data isn't being saved. Delete button is working fine(whenever i delete a polygon it is deleted and also in the geoserver published layer) but editing, draw polygon, line,point are not working fine ie i am able to draw or edit the polygon or line, but is not saved and whenever i refresh the page it is showing the previous polygon not the edited one nor newly inserted one

The bit of my code for posting is:

```
            var dirty = {};
        var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
        var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
            // featureNS: 'http://argeomatica.com',
            featureNS: 'http://www.opengis.net/cite',
            // featureType: 'playa_sample',
            featureType: 'NARAYANGARH',
            service: 'WFS',
                        version: '1.1.0',
                        request: 'GetFeature',
                        srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
        var transactWFS = function(p,f) {
            switch(p) {
            case 'insert':
                node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f],null,null,formatGML);
                break;
            case 'update':
                node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,formatGML);
                break;
            case 'delete':
                node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],formatGML);
                break;
            }
            s = new XMLSerializer();
            str = s.serializeToString(node);
            // $.ajax('http://geoserver-dbauszus.rhcloud.com/wfs',{
                $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wfs',{
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'xml',
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'text/xml',
                data: str
                }).done();
        }

        $('.btn-floating').hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).addClass('darken-2');},
                function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('darken-2');}
                );

        $('.btnMenu').on('click', function(event) {
            $('.btnMenu').removeClass('orange');
            $(this).addClass('orange');
            map.removeInteraction(interaction);
            select.getFeatures().clear();
            map.removeInteraction(select);
            switch($(this).attr('id')) {

            case 'btnSelect':
                interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
                    style: new ol.style.Style({
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#f50057', width: 2})
                        })
                });
                map.addInteraction(interaction);
                interaction.getFeatures().on('add', function(e) {
                    props = e.element.getProperties();
                    if (props.status){$('#popup-status').html(props.status);}else{$('#popup-status').html('n/a');}
                    if (props.tiendas){$('#popup-tiendas').html(props.tiendas);}else{$('#popup-tiendas').html('n/a');}
                    coord = $('.ol-mouse-position').html().split(',');
                    overlayPopup.setPosition(coord);
                    });
                break;

            case 'btnEdit':
                map.addInteraction(select);
                interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                    features: select.getFeatures()
                    });
                map.addInteraction(interaction);

                snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
                    source: layerVector.getSource()
                    });
                map.addInteraction(snap);

                dirty = {};
                select.getFeatures().on('add', function(e) {
                    e.element.on('change', function(e) {
                        dirty[e.target.getId()] = true;
                        });
                    });
                select.getFeatures().on('remove', function(e) {
                    f = e.element;
                    if (dirty[f.getId()]){
                        delete dirty[f.getId()];
                        featureProperties = f.getProperties();
                        delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
                        var clone = new ol.Feature(featureProperties);
                        clone.setId(f.getId());
                        transactWFS('update',clone);
                        }
                    });
                break;

            case 'btnDrawPoint':
                interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                    type: 'Point',
                    source: layerVector.getSource()
                });
                map.addInteraction(interaction);
                interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
                    transactWFS('insert',e.feature);
                });
                break;

            case 'btnDrawLine':
                interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                    type: 'LineString',
                    source: layerVector.getSource()
                });
                map.addInteraction(interaction);
                interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
                    transactWFS('insert',e.feature);
                });
                break;

            case 'btnDrawPoly':
                interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                    type: 'Polygon',
                    source: layerVector.getSource()
                });
                map.addInteraction(interaction);
                interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
                    transactWFS('insert',e.feature);
                });
                break;

            case 'btnDelete':
                interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
                map.addInteraction(interaction);
                interaction.getFeatures().on('change:length', function(e) {
                    transactWFS('delete',e.target.item(0));
                    interaction.getFeatures().clear();
                    selectPointerMove.getFeatures().clear();
                });
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            });
```

This code generates the following XML:

```
    <Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Update xmlns:feature="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wfs" typeName="feature:NARAYANGARH">
    <Property>
      <Name>the_geom</Name>
      <Value>
        <MultiPolygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <polygonMember>
            <Polygon> 
              <exterior>
                <LinearRing>
                  <posList>8571089.53392887 3553005.14086169 ...</posList>
                </LinearRing>
              </exterior>
            </Polygon>
          </polygonMember>
        </MultiPolygon>
      </Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>Name</Name>
      <Value>153-HRAM0832-KH1716</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>Shape_Leng</Name>
      <Value>554.269739142</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>Shape_Area</Name>
      <Value>16820.1029665</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>WAQF_ID</Name>
      <Value>HRAM0832</Value>
    </Property>
    ....
        <Property>
          <Name>Longitude</Name>
          <Value>76.996029</Value>
        </Property>
        <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
          <FeatureId fid="NARAYANGARH.164"/>
        </Filter>
      </Update>
    </Transaction>
```

My main problem now is how to make the edit buttons save user edits to the WFS layer?
please tell me where the problem is

Comment: please add the XML being sent to the server, the response sent back from the server and any relevant part of the GeoServer log file to the question

Comment: which xml file you want? please mention that

Comment: the one sent when you make an edit, the one sent back from the server

Comment: here is my xml file                                                                                                                        https://jsfiddle.net/rishe/mzq4cwc1/

Comment: that is a getFeature response - what does your client send to GeoServer?

Comment: from where i can get this xml file? please mention that

Comment: look in the network tab of your javascript debugger

Comment: In my code, while debugging                                                                      s = new XMLSerializer();
            str = s.serializeToString(node);
                                                                                                                 str is                                                          https://jsfiddle.net/rishe/8nkayjon/    in the xml file it is showing the updated point also, but it is not updated in the shapefile only delete option is reflecting in the shapefile

Comment: any updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this line is wrong:

```
<Update xmlns:feature="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wfs" typeName="feature:NARAYANGARH">
```

the URI after feature should be the same URI that you set in your workspace for the data store.

However looking at the returned error message from GeoServer should give a fuller idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: in code i have mentioned as  typename: 'NARAYANGARH', if i mention  typename: 'cite:NARAYANGARH', then in the xml file it is showing as typeName="feature:cite:NARAYANGARH". How to look the returned error message from geoserver?

Comment: log file of geoserver is https://jsfiddle.net/rishe/Lur8e8bg/

Comment: Anybody please solve the problem

Comment: did you try with the correct URI?